# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter can not parse its outcome text

Tags: java

After I get the formatted value from DateTimeFormatter instance, I faced An Exception when I tried to parse the formatted value by the same DateTimeFormatter instance.

My Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMdHms");
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.DECEMBER, 9, 22, 9, 3);
        String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter); // "1986-04-08 12:30"
        formatter.parse(formattedDateTime);
        System.out.println(formattedDateTime);
}
```

The Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20191292293' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1777)
    at com.yemencafe.service.DirectoryCipherService.main(DirectoryCipherService.java:24)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: That's a difficult string to parse. For example `2019129` could be `2019-12-09` or `2019-01-29`. How can the parser tell?

Comment: Well, use a better, readable, unambiguous format.